# Resolve alias from NPM link

Tags: vue.js, hyperlink, alias

I have a Vue app that is using [`link-module-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/link-module-alias) in some places like this:

```
import MyPage from '@/components/MyPage'
```

In `main.js` of that app, I am exporting the entire app as a variable.

```
export const VueApp = () => {

  var app = new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')

  return app
}
```

This app gets built and published to NPM. I can require it in another Vue app, and just put `VueApp()` on the main page to reproduce the site.

In the root folder of that project, I ran:

```
npm link
```

...as we want to set up a dev environment for development of project that is going to consume the NPM package eventually.

In a new project, I consume the local NPM package with this command:

```
npm link myapp
```

After that, I can see all the source code in the `node_modules/myapp` folder.

Running the app, I get an error:

```
These dependencies were not found

@/components/MyPage in /Users/<username>/source/myapp/src/index.js
```

I believe I need to add a `resolve` to a `webpack.config.js` for the `@` character. I don't have a `webpack.config.js`, but I do have a `vue.config.js`.

I'm just not sure how to add the `resolve` to `vue.config.js`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Vue CLI docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/troubleshooting.html#symbolic-links-in-node-modules):

> ### Symbolic Links in `node_modules`
>
> If there're dependencies installed by `npm link` or `yarn link`, ESLint (and sometimes Babel as well) may not work > properly for those symlinked dependencies. It is because [webpack resolves symlinks to their real locations by default](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvesymlinks), thus breaks ESLint / Babel config lookup.
>
> A workaround for this issue is to manually disable symlinks resolution in webpack:
>
> ```js
> // vue.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   chainWebpack: (config) => {
>     config.resolve.symlinks(false)
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Warning:**
>   Disabling `resolve.symlinks` may break hot module reloading if your dependencies are installed by third-party npm clients that utilized symbolic links, such as`cnpm` or `pnpm`.

You'll need to create [`<project-root>/vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Sigh.. This was the one thing I had tried.. I have a vue.config.js and I have tried that chainWebpack: code above. The problem persists.

Comment: Did you solve this? It doesn't work for me too. @DoblyTufnell